# Update on view over partitioned tables updating all clustered indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-update, partitioning

We have a table, which is partitioned through a date field into separate years.

There is a view over all of these tables (Call)

Schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Call_2015](
    [calID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [calPackageID] [int] NULL,
    [calClientID] [int] NULL,
    [calStartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [calEndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [calTimeIn] [char](5) NULL,
    [calTimeOut] [char](5) NULL,
    [calMinutes] [smallint] NULL,
    [calPreferredTimeIn] [char](5) NULL,
    [calPreferredTimeOut] [char](5) NULL,
    [calActualTimeIn] [char](5) NULL,
    [calActualTimeOut] [char](5) NULL,
    [calActualMinutes] [smallint] NULL,
    [calConfirmed] [smallint] NULL,
    [calCarerID] [int] NULL,
    [calRepCarerID] [int] NULL,
    [calOriginalCarerID] [int] NULL,
    [calContractID] [int] NULL,
    [calNeedID] [int] NULL,
    [calMedicationID] [int] NULL,
    [calFrequency] [smallint] NULL,
    [calFromDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [calWeekNo] [smallint] NULL,
    [calAlert] [smallint] NULL,
    [calNoLeave] [smallint] NULL,
    [calTimeCritical] [smallint] NULL,
    [calStatus] [smallint] NULL,
    [calClientAwayReasonID] [int] NULL,
    [calCarerAwayReasonID] [int] NULL,
    [calOutsideShift] [smallint] NULL,
    [calHistoryID] [int] NULL,
    [calInvoiceID] [int] NULL,
    [calWagesheetID] [int] NULL,
    [calReasonID] [int] NULL,
    [calCallConfirmID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [calCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [calUpdated] [datetime] NULL,
    [calVariation] [int] NULL,
    [calVariationUserID] [int] NULL,
    [calException] [smallint] NULL,
    [calRetained] [smallint] NULL,
    [calDoubleUpID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [calDoubleUpOrder] [smallint] NULL,
    [calNeedCount] [smallint] NULL,
    [calNoStay] [smallint] NULL,
    [calCoverCarerID] [int] NULL,
    [calPayAdjustment] [real] NULL,
    [calChargeAdjustment] [real] NULL,
    [calTeamID] [int] NULL,
    [calExpenses] [money] NULL,
    [calMileage] [real] NULL,
    [calOverrideStatus] [smallint] NULL,
    [calLocked] [smallint] NULL,
    [calDriver] [smallint] NULL,
    [calPostcode] [char](10) NULL,
    [calDayCentreID] [int] NULL,
    [calMustHaveCarer] [smallint] NULL,
    [calRoleID] [int] NULL,
    [calUnavailableCarerID] [int] NULL,
    [calClientInformed] [smallint] NULL,
    [calFamilyInformed] [smallint] NULL,
    [calMonthlyDay] [smallint] NULL,
    [calOriginalTimeIn] [char](5) NULL,
    [calLeadCarer] [smallint] NULL,
    [calCallTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [calActualStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [calActualEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Table_Year] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Call_2015] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Table_Year] ASC,
    [calID] ASC,
    [calStartDate] ASC,
    [calEndDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Call_2015]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Call_Year_2015] CHECK  (([Table_Year]=(2015)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Call_2015] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Call_Year_2015]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Call_2015]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_calStartDate_2015] CHECK  (([calStartDate]>=CONVERT([datetime],'01 Jan 2015 00:00:00',(0)) AND [calStartDate]<=CONVERT([datetime],'31 DEC 2015 23:59:59',(0))))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Call_2015] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_calStartDate_2015]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Call_2015] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Call_2015_Table_Year]  DEFAULT ((2015)) FOR [Table_Year]
GO
```

The update to the table is as follows:

```
UPDATE Call SET
        calStartDate = CASE 
            WHEN calFrequency = 14 THEN dbo.funDate(@MonthlyDay, MONTH(calStartDate), YEAR(calStartDate))
            WHEN calFrequency IN (15,16) THEN dbo.funMonthlyCallDate(calFrequency, @MonthlyDay, calStartDate)
            ELSE DateAdd(d, @StartDay-1, (calStartDate - datepart(dw,calStartDate)+1)) 
        END,
        calEndDate = CASE 
            WHEN calFrequency = 14 THEN dbo.funDate(@MonthlyDay + @EndDay - @StartDay, MONTH(calStartDate), YEAR(calStartDate))
            WHEN calFrequency IN (15,16) THEN DATEADD(D, @EndDay - @StartDay, dbo.funMonthlyCallDate(calFrequency, @MonthlyDay, calStartDate))
            ELSE DateAdd(d, @StartDay-1+@DayCount, (calStartDate - datepart(dw,calStartDate)+1)) 
        END,
        calTimeIn = @TimeIn,
        calTimeOut = @TimeOut,
        calMinutes = @Minutes,
        calMonthlyDay = @MonthlyDay,
        calClientInformed = Null, 
        calFamilyInformed = Null
    WHERE calPackageID = @PackageID
    AND calClientID = @ClientID
    AND calWeekNo = @WeekNo
    AND (DatePart(dw, calStartDate) = @OriginalDay OR calFrequency IN (14,15,16))
    AND calStartDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND (calInvoiceID = 0 OR calInvoiceID Is Null OR @InvoicesFinalised = 1)
    AND (calWagesheetID = 0 OR calWagesheetID Is Null OR @WagesFinalised = 1)
    AND (calLocked = 0 OR calLocked Is Null)
    AND (Table_Year = YEAR(@StartDate) 
            OR Table_Year =YEAR(@EndDate))
```

The SP updates a batch of rows dependant of input into @StartDate and @EndDate (updates all rows with a calStartDate between the two)

The problem then comes with the execution plan. There are huge IO costs to the operation, and I've nailed it down to how SQL is dealing with the update.

Currently we have 20 of these tables; partitioned per year. Each update is causing an update of every single table's indexes, regardless of whether the table is actually touched by the update operation or not.

[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhn1R.png)

Below this section it goes on to update, in the exact same manner, every table in the view.

I cannot see why this is, as I have specified the Table_Year (which the table is partitioned on) within the query text. Shouldn't SQL only update the necessary table?